# Asp.net CheckBox.Enabled = false problem

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

Why on earth asp.net CheckBox doesn't render to a client-html if you set the Enabled property to False on the server-side ?
Purpose of having Enabled=false is simple - you don't want user to change the CheckBox sometimes. Thx for your help !

Answer (score 3):

You want READONLY.